Prove: For every $\epsilon>0$, $100 n \log_2 n \leq \epsilon n^2$ for every sufficiently large $n$.
Prove: For every $\epsilon>0$, $100 n \log_2 n \leq \epsilon n^2$ for every sufficiently large $n$.
Here's what I tried: When $n$ is large enough, $n$ must be greater than 0, so both sides of the above inequality can be reduced by one $n$. The result after reduction is:
$$ 100 \log_2 ⁡n \leq \epsilon n.$$
By moving $n$ on the right side of the inequality to the left, we get
$$\frac{100 \log_2 ⁡n}{n} \leq \epsilon.$$
Then I didn't know how to continue.

For the equality, can you (or not) use Lambert function ?

Can you see how it's equivalent to proving $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{2^x} =0$?

To Claude Leibovici: I cannot see the relationship between Lambert function and my question.

To Chris Lewis: I do not understand.

For $n=2^x$ you get what Chris Lewis was suggesting.

Let $\varepsilon \mapsto C \varepsilon $ where $C = 100 / \ln \left( 2 \right)$. See we are proving that
$$\frac {\ln \left( n \right)}{n} < \varepsilon$$
for sufficiently large $n$. To this end, define $x = \ln \left( n \right)$ and see
$$\frac {x}{{e}^{x}} = \frac {x}{\sum_{k \ge 0} {x}^{k} / k!} < \frac {x}{{x}^{2} / 2} = \frac {2}{x}.$$
Let $N = 2 / \varepsilon$. For all $n > {e}^{N}$, it is known for certain that $\ln \left( n \right) / n < \varepsilon$. $\blacksquare$
